# Creating Ajax website with links of multiple subfolders is failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, .htaccess

I'm trying to create a **site** that is **loading** all it's **content via Ajax**. So let's say the site is **www.abc.net**.

I have **abc.net/index.html** and this file shall always being called, whatever URL(folder/file) was typed in. So e.g. **abc.net/somesubsite** was called, the URL should stay as it is and just calling the index.html.

The idea is now to look which URL was called and to handle that with jQuery and showing the specific div. In that way a direct link would be easily possible.

Well my issue is that I'm not able to let the URL stay as it is and when having **abc.net/somesubsite/someother** then I get an server error. I was playing around with htaccess but it feels that it's not really a perfect solution.

Is there good way to do that? It is like [this site](http://html5.gingerhost.com/seattle) but I want to be able to handle folder/subfolder which is not possible there. I'm interested in any solution, it's also no problem to have different html files that are loaded if really needed. But if possible I would like to have all in one file.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to look into a framework for developing single-page web applications, such as [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org)?

Comment: Well might be an idea but no solution because there I would have the same issues with deep linking I think. Also figured out now how to do that with simple javascript =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your .htaccess file like so:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will redirect all relevant server calls to `index.php?url=<rest of the url>`.

Now, rename your `index.html` to `index.php` (we need to write a little php code).

In your JavaScript write:

```
var url = "<?php echo $_GET['url']; ?>";
```

And there you have it. You can now split the string by '/' delimiter to find all your needed components.

As per your example, the following url: `abc.net/somesubsite/someother` will redirect to `index.php` and the `url` variable will hold `somesubsite/someother`.

You can then use `url.split('/')` to get all "subfolders" in an array.

You will also have to override all links' behavior in your site:

1. Prevent the normal action
2. Load the ajax content
3. pushState to change the url

like so:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); // 1
    var $url = this.href;
    loadContent($url); // 2 
    window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", $url); // 3        
});
```

Comment: When I go abc.net/somesubsite then the index.php is redirected. When I go abc.net/somesubsite/somesite it does not load the css stuff correctly. How to fix that? I mean both is bad for me. I need a hidden redirect and yeah fixed css pathes =/

Comment: use html `<base href="http://example.net">` tag in your `<head>` section to set the base address of your site. The htaccess redirect I gave you will not redirect .css files. The first line that ends with `! -f` means: If this url doesn't point to a file

Comment: Cool, thanks I didn't know. Okay so that fixed the multiple subfolder issue. But still when I go abc.net/somesubsite I'm redirect to the index.php. How can I fix that?

Comment: Do you have it live so I can see the problem?

Comment: Not really, sorry. And there is another issue. I have for sure links like abc.net/somesubsite/somesite but now this is not Ajax on page loaded anymore. It's now completely reloading the page, maybe that's the reason?

Comment: To do that you will have to override the links' click event.. look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) for changing the url without redirecting the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71209/discussion-between-yotam-omer-and-kwoxer).