# SVG href ID is not found when being on a subsite/subfolder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, .htaccess, svg

This issue is concerning another topic: [Creating Ajax website with links of multiple subfolders is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593650/creating-ajax-website-with-links-of-multiple-subfolders-is-failing/).
Please also have a look into the discussion where the solution for that issue was found.

My current issue with that solution is that when now being on a subsite like **example.net/about** all the ID's used by my SVG elements are not found anymore. So all my textpathes are located on the 0,0 coordinates on my map instead of the specific path I gave to them. Also SVG graphics are not located on the right place anymore. But being on **example.net** everything is still working fine!

So let's take the following example which is just one of my 500 elements and just the textpath elements. This is working as expected on abc.net but on abc.net/about the ID is not found anymore:

```
<path id="text1" d="M1585.621635966945,...some long path..."></path>
<textPath xlink:href="#text1">Some Text</textPath>
```

That for sure does make sense because on example.net/about#text1 there is not such an ID. So I was thinking about changing the href url. In the following I show you what I tried out and if it worked on "**page**(example.net)" or "**subpage**(example.net/about)":

1. `<textPath xlink:href="#text1">Some Text</textPath>`
   **page** working, **subpage** not working
2. `<textPath xlink:href="http://example.net/#text1">Some Text</textPath>`
   **page** working, **subpage** not working
3. `<textPath xlink:href="http://example.net/text1">Some Text</textPath>`
   **page** not working, **subpage** not working
4. `<textPath xlink:href="http://example.net/index.html#text1">Some Text</textPath>`
   **page** not working, **subpage** not working
5. `<textPath xlink:href="http://example.net/index.html#text1">Some Text</textPath>`
   **page** not working, **subpage** not working

I also have the `<base href="http://example.net">`set in the index.html head.

So how can I use the hashbang href way on connecting textpathes with SVG's.

Also the current htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

One idea that came to my mind right now was to set `window.location.pathname="/"`but unfortunately the page is reloading all the time now. So telling him a different URL even though using another is not really working out.

Also very interesting docs here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html but was not able find a solution from that.

Comment: are you using a `<base>` tag? That's the cause of your problems if you are.

Comment: Hey good point. Indeed removing that is fixing this issue... but! as from the discussing of the other topic I need that base thing because I also would like to use www.example.net/about/creator So how can I get that running without the base meta tag?

Comment: And also www.example.net/about/ is not working anymore when removing the base tag. So I think the base tag is a good thing I'll need overall, isn't it?

Comment: If you have a `<base>` tag you'll need to convert all the xlink:href values to absolute URIs

Comment: Could you maybe give an example for that? I mean didn't I have tried the same already?

Comment: You really need to provide a link to some demonstration of your problem. Absolute URIs should work so maybe there's something else going on.

Comment: Could that work with a free hoster? I mean the whole special about this is that I need a htaccess, isn't it? Or maybe I just have done a small mistake in the absolute path. So what I wrong about "http://example.net/#text1"?

Comment: Are you including the svg filename in your absolute path? Ie. `http://example.net/mysvg.svg#text1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is working fine:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:css|js|maps|pics) [NC]
RewriteRule (/(?:css|js|maps|pics)/.*)$ $1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

So rewriting the base in htaccess instead of in the index.html is the way to go. The additional rewrite reule above makes sure that also on example.net/about/creator you still find the correct css and so files.