# htaccess is not redirecting multiple virtual subfolders correctly

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect, svg

This question is concerning these both questions:
[Creating Ajax website with links of multiple subfolders is failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593650/creating-ajax-website-with-links-of-multiple-subfolders-is-failing/) and [SVG href ID is not found when being on a subsite/subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28605609/svg-href-id-is-not-found-when-being-on-a-subsite-subfolder) but it's not needed to be read.

So I just would like to know how I can **enable** the **redirect on muliple subfolders** with **htaccess**. This is my current htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

Btw: I removed the whole base path meta tag in the index.html, because it made more trouble than having any use for me.

Basically the website is shown **correctly** on:

- example.net
- example.net/
- example.net/about

but it is **not working** on:

- example.net/about/
- example.net/about/creator

So how can I change the htaccress file so that also the last two URLs are redirected the the index.html. I mean that issue here is I believe **not a SVG question**, it is a really simple **htaccess issue**.

### After some investigation...

I found out that the redirect is correct. Just all the external css, js and so on files are not correctly located.

So how can I use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" media="screen"/>
```

instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/css/default.css" media="screen"/>
```

without the base path meta tag. If I change the relative to absolute path anywhere on my code, it is working...

I know that it's bizzar. But as you can see there are pros and cons of the base path. As well as the absolute and relative pathes.

Comment: Do you have more rewrite rules or just these ones? Or any other .htaccess in your system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exclude your css, js and image files from redirection by adding the following.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:css|js|maps|pics) [NC]
RewriteRule (/(?:css|js|maps|pics)/.*)$ $1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Surely they would be skipped anyway (`!-f`)? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: With your both ideas it is not working anymore and any URL =/

Comment: Please try the updated rule. I'm assuming that your css, js, image directories are all located in the root directory. The idea here is to strip the extra dirs that get added because of using a relative href value like "css/style.css" or "js/script.js".

Comment: Tried the updated one and now example.net/about/creator works partially. But I see something. I think there is some issue beside this. Gimme a sec.

Comment: Maybe your folder structures differ quite a bit based on file types. If you can post that then probably using multiple rules can offer a better solution.

Comment: Ohh indeed I think I have the issue. Btw I have these in my folder. index.html,.htaccess, and the folders css/,js/,maps/,pics/

Comment: But the special is that I have the js librarys in a subfolder in the js folder. And in the console of my browser it seems to be the reason because it starts with failing of my 4 librarys. And it fits to the htaccess where we do no go into subfolder.

Comment: So what would you say? 1. Put the js lib folder in the root. 2. going depper with htaccess

Comment: But all of your resource files are in these four dirs only, right?

Comment: That's right. So the issue is that js/libs/ is not handled

Comment: Whis this nothing is found anymore not even on example.net =/ Btw console now says "http://localhost/about/js/libs/d3.min.js" so that **about** must be deleted somehow.

Comment: I played a bit around with your examples and searched a bit. I found this one here which is working for me as expected: RewriteRule /(([^/]*)(.*)((?:css|js|maps|pics)/.*))$ /$1 [NC,L]

Comment: Also tested your version which is also working. Great now we have 2 solutions =) Thanks a lot and maybe which one is better in terms of being faster or so?

Comment: If both are working without any problems with sub/sub/sub dirs as well.. use yours as it's not conditional.